# Is there an easy way to wrap a vue.js frontend in an electron app?

Tags: vue.js, electron

I have a vue.js app which connects to an API which can be running on one of many servers. It is currently served on a web server, but I would like to give clients the option to run it as a desktop application, which connects to the same API, so that if the front end server is down, they can still connect to the API server of their choice. Ideally, I wouldn't make any changes to the front end--I would just wrap it in an electron app.

Is there an easy approach to make this happen?

Comment: Maybe scaffold an `electron-vue` project, and copy your project into it.

Answer (score 2):

I think using `vue add electron-builder` is the easiest way to add electron to an existing vue app. This is assuming you are using `vue-cli`. [Docs](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder).

Comment: vue-cli is not advised to be used right now, because it is in maintenance mode. (https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html).
Now if I want to use just a standard vue3 app and wrap it into an electron app. Can't I do that without any other dependency? I just wonder if I would meet some hurdles if I tried to combine the two without any other packages. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to take an existing template and adds your front-end to it. I recently [did a review of the best Electron frameworks of this May (2021)](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/wiki/State-of-Electron-frameworks-%5BMay-2021%5D), and found that if you want to create a Vue Electron app, you are best off with choosing [vite-electron-builder](https://github.com/cawa-93/vite-electron-builder).

There are some security recommendations you should add in order to make your app more secure, but it looks like a solid choice from my review.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that.